# Check CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

What is the code to check if anything is checked in a `CheckedListBox`. I am making an application to register Movies, and I need to check the Genres of the movies from the `CheckedListBox`. If nothing is checked, a `MessageBox` should appear telling you *You need to select a Genre for the movie.*

Answer (score 1):

You should check `CheckedItems` or `CheckedIndices` properties, depending on what you need

```
CheckedListBox cl = new CheckedListBox();

if (cl.CheckedIndices.Count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You need to select a Genre for the movie.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the [`SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex.aspx) property:

```
if(checkListBoxGenre.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You need to select a Genre for the movie.");
}
```

Another option is to use the [`Text` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.text.aspx) which gets the text of the currently selected item in the ListBox.

```
if(checkListBoxGenre.Text.Length == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You need to select a Genre for the movie.");
}
```

It's just a matter of readability and personal preferences.

Comment: I did it like this : 
else if (GenreCheck.Text.Length == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select the Genre(s) of the movie.");
                }

And it works xD

Comment: @user1957558: The `Text` property returns the text of the first selected item. But i would use `SelectedIndex` if i want to know if something is selected. It's just a matter of readability and personal preferences. But edited my answer to take that into account.

Comment: @user1957558 checking text isn't good. Better check one of two properties from my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
if(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
{
   // If so, loop through all checked items and print results.
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("You need to select a Genre for the movie.");
}
```